# Fetch posts from Post collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Node. I am stuck somewhere and need a little help.

I am doing a get request for getting the posts from posts collection and show it to users, but the showPosts route should only show the post from the users or hashtag he follows. I am using NodeJS

For example: There is a user X who follows [A,B,C] so in the showPosts route it should only show the recent posts from A/B/C only. I am having the list of followings in the user collection and all the posts are in different collection.

Does anyone have idea about this?
Or is there any blog or something where I can get some help!!

Comment: You could do this through you database select sql. Would help if you told us wath you already have tried and how is your code right now, is difficult to help without knowing those things

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could achieve what you are looking for.

I would suggest adding a field to your user schema consisting of an array of the user ids he or she is following. Then a simple find() as follows will do the trick:

```
Post.find({
    '_id': { $in: FOLLOWED_USERS}
}, function(err, docs){
     console.log(docs);
});
```

Comment: I have, followed user in the same document but the posts are in different collection. Can you please tell how to get posts from that collection based on followed users. How to join two collection in mongoose

Comment: Search in the posts collection with the query provided